# Append element not to end, before last element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, append

I'm trying to post comment with an AJAX post. But last `comment` element contains submit button. And after appending, new item appears after submit button.

```
<div class="commentContainer" >

    <div class="comment">
        <div class="commentText">Any comment1 ... </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comment">
        <div class="commentText">Any comment2 ... </div>
    </div>
        ....................................
    <div class="comment"> 
        <div class="sendPanel">
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and result of posting request:

```
success: function (result)  {
    if (result.success) {
         $('.commentContainer').append('<div class="comment"><div class="commentText">' + result.text + '</div></div>');
    }   
}
```

I want to keep submit button on the end always. How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for all for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  $('<div class="comment"><div class="commentText">' + result.text + '</div></div>')
   .insertBefore('commentContainer .comment:last-child');
```

Or even better

```
$('<div>', {'class': 'comment'}).append(
    $('<div>', {'class': 'commentText', text: result.text})
).insertBefore('.commentContainer .comment:last-child');
```

This one is better for performance

> ## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfRwH/)

[jQuery last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

[jQuery insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :last pseudo-selector:
try this:

```
success: function (result) 
    {
        if (result.success) 
        {
            $('.commentContainer').find('div:last').before('<div class="comment"><div class="commentText">' + result.text + '</div></div>');
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 success: function (result) 
    {
        if (result.success) 
        {
             $('<div class="comment"><div class="commentText">' + result.text + '</div></div>').insertBefore('.commentContainer .comment:last');
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question specifically asked about `jQuery` but this can be done with plain JS quite neatly, with the `insertBefore()` function, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). (I came across this post while looking for a solution to a similar problem but not using jQuery)

```
ul = document.getElementById('my-list-id'); //Get the list from the DOM
li = document.createElement('li'); // Create the element to append

ul.insertBefore(li, ul.lastChild); // Append the element before the last child
```